# What does it mean when part of one's health bar stays red?

Tags: skullgirls

I've noticed sometimes when I hit enemies their life bars stay filled in but red, instead of draining to black. In the current case it's a team battle. I've seen similar happen in other fighting games where part of the health bar is "damaged" but sticks around until you can finish a combo/etc, but in this case the red bar doesn't appear to go down if I stop attacking. When the red reaches the end of the character's health bar, they still go down. I've also noticed some attacks deal both "black" damage that drains immediately and some "red" damage that doesn't drain until the opponent is KO'd.

What's the purpose of the red, "sticky" part of the health bar? Do characters have an opportunity to gain some of that health back? Do some attacks/circumstances cause "red" damage instead of "black" damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is [Recoverable Damage](http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Skullgirls/Game_Elements/Life_and_Damage#Recoverable_Damage):

> All attacks, including chip damage from blocked attacks, deal some portion of recoverable damage. Throws deal 100% recoverable damage. Life recovery begins when a character tags out or is otherwise off screen, starting at 90f after leaving. This recovery is always percentage based, at a rate of .5% per 30f. Team size and the remaining life totals do not effect life recovery in any way.

So when you have a large portion of red health left, you can switch to a higher-health teammate to let some of your health recover. Note if you use assists your teammate can still take damage during non-invincible attack frames, so they're not 100% safe even in reserve if you use them for assists.

Recoverable damage doesn't happen to single characters and is useless for the last surviving character on a team.